# Dojo Dgrid shows poor performance in IE8

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-8, dojo, treegrid, dgrid

We have created tree dgrid. It is a editable grid with validation text box and number text box. When we edit a cell in the tree grid it shows a lag(ie.while typing in the keyboard, it appears in the screen after few seconds). But it works seamlessly in FF.

Is there any configuration that has to be taken care while working in IE8(or any old browsers)?

Comment: I've never heard of any configuration that does that. and IE8 is an old bugged browser, and all my application on dojo work really slow when I am using it. so personally if i have to support IE8 or lower I try to build a different simpler application just to serve minimal functionality.

Comment: You're going to need to provide actual code for us to try to reproduce the performance issue you're seeing, otherwise there's really no way we can help to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple facts:

- `dgrid/tree` uses event delegation to listen for clicks, double clicks and key-downs on the tree column.
- `dojo/query` uses `dojo/selector/acme` as the query engine in IE8.

Acme does a terrible job processing the selector used by `dgrid/tree`.  The more rows in your grid, the worse it gets.

Until a fix is made in dgrid, a work around is to set the `expandOn` property of your tree column and use a simple selector.  If you only want to support mouse clicks to expand and shrink rows, this works:

```
expandOn: '.dgrid-expando-icon:click'
```

Otherwise, you will need a selector that only matches on something in a row and not in the grid's header.